# Domain specific bookmarks for Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I while back Firefox had an extension called InDomain Bookmarks, that filters your bookmarks and displays only those for the domain you are in. The extension came with a toolbar that made it easy to navigate sites I frequent. Any idea what happened to it or if there any alternatives?

Chrome has something called [Find My Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-my-bookmarks/cahmhjehomglimoklhidcfdlfmahlold?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) which has similar functionality.

Comment: Why not just copy/paste the domain into a (ctrl+b) bookmark search?

Comment: I'm looking for a quick way to navigate sites that I develop. InDomain extension provided me with a one-click method to get to any of the pages I frequent. I could as easily go to the address bar and type **test loc perf** if I wanted to go to *http://test.local/admin/config/development/performance* and Firefox will give me a list of matching pages to choose from. The one-click thing is key.

Comment: [Location bar search](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Location_Bar_search) could be helpful?? To filter bookmarks, enter a **\*** followed by a space and the bookmarked site/domain name. If the sites are also [tagged in the bookmarks library](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/categorizing-bookmarks-make-them-easy-to-find) (for example as **Internal Site**), then use `+ internal`.

Comment: @vWil that is the method I am using currently. Works ok but I guess I'm a bit pedantic. I failed to mention, before, that the extension came with a toolbar. It really made things easy for me.

Comment: Oh the [extension still exists here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/indomainbookmarks) but doesn't work on recent Firefox versions.